# code flows to unexpected overloaded method

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

I got an assignment for a course i am taking in CS.

One of the questions has has some classes and a main method and i am asked what will be the output and through which method the code will go.

I worked it out in my head by following the code. After that i ran the code to see what would happen. and what happened really surprised me. It looks like the reference of the object changes the method the JVM selects.

How is it possible that cases 2 and 4 goes to method 1 but case 3 goes to method 3. I would really like to understand what is happening.

class AA:

```
public class AA
{
private int _val=0;
public AA()
{
    _val = 5;
}
public AA(int val)
{
    _val = val;
}
public int getVal()
{
    return _val;
}
public void setVal(int val)
{
    _val = val;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "val ="+_val;
}
}
```

class BB:

```
public class BB extends AA
{
private String _st;

public BB()
{
    _st = "bb";
}
public BB(String st, int val)
{
    super(val);
    _st = st;
}
public String getSt()
{
    return _st;
}

// 1
public boolean equals(Object ob)
{
    if ((ob != null) && (ob instanceof BB))
    {
        if(_st.equals(((BB)ob)._st)&&(getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
        {
            System.out.println("fun 1: true");
            return true;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("fun 1: false");
    return false;
}
// 2
public boolean equals(AA ob)
{
    if ((ob != null) && (ob instanceof BB))
    {
        if (_st.equals(((BB) ob)._st)&& (getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
        {
            System.out.println("fun 2: true");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("fun 2: false");
    return false;
}
// 3

public boolean equals(BB ob)
{
    if (ob != null)
    {
        if (_st.equals(((BB) ob)._st)&& (getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
        {
            System.out.println("fun 3: true");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("fun 3: false");
    return false;
}
}
```

and this is the main:

```
public class Driver
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    AA a1 = new AA();
    AA a2 = new BB();
    AA a3 = new AA();
    AA a4 = new BB();
    BB b1 = new BB();
    BB b2 = new BB();

    //12
    System.out.println("12: a3 equals a1 is " +a3.equals(a1));
    //13
    System.out.println("13: a4 equals a2 is " + a4.equals(a2));
    //14
    System.out.println("14: a1 equals a2 is " +a1.equals(a2));
    //15
    System.out.println("15: a2 equals b1 is " +a2.equals(b1));
    //16
    System.out.println("16: b1 equals a1 is " +b1.equals(a1));
    //17
    System.out.println("17: b2 equals b1 is " +b2.equals(b1));
    //18
    System.out.println("18: b1 equals a4 is " +b1.equals(a4));
}
}
```

the output that i am getting is this:

```
1: a3 equals a1 is false
fun 1: true
2: a4 equals a2 is true
3: a1 equals a2 is false
fun 1: true
4: a2 equals b1 is true
fun 2: false
5: b1 equals a1 is false
fun 3: true
6: b2 equals b1 is true
fun 2: true
7: b1 equals a4 is true
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules to remember for which method is chosen and why are:

1. The method signature is chosen by the compiler during compilation.
2. The override is chosen at runtime, depending on the runtime type of the object on which the method is called.

Running through your cases:

> 1: a3 equals a1 is false

The objects `a3` and `a1` are both of type `AA`.  The `equals` method chosen is `equals(Object)`, inherited from `Object`, because `AA` doesn't override or overload it.  They are different objects, so `equals` returns `false`.  No `fun` message is printed.

> fun 1: true
>
> 2: a4 equals a2 is true

The objects `a4` and `a2` are both of type `BB`, but the reference variables are of type `AA`.  The compile-time signature is `equals(Object)`, because that is the only method named "equals" that exists on type `AA`.  At runtime, there is an override in `BB`, `equals(Object)`, that is chosen, because `a4` refers to an object of type `BB`.  The override prints `fun 1` and returns `true`.

> 3: a1 equals a2 is false

The reference variables are both of type `AA`, but `a1` refers to a `AA` object while `a2` refers to a `BB` object.  The compile-time signature is `equals(Object)`, because `AA` doesn't override it.  At runtime, `equals(Object)` is chosen from `Object` because `AA` doesn't override it.  They are different objects, so `equals` returns `false`.  No `fun` message is printed.

> fun 1: true
>
> 4: a2 equals b1 is true

The objects `a2` and `b1` are of type `BB`, but the variable `a2` is of type `AA` while the variable `b1` is of type `BB`.  The compile-time signature is `equals(Object)`, because `AA` doesn't override or overload it.  At runtime, there is an override in `BB`, `equals(Object)`, that is chosen, because `a2` refers to an object of type `BB`.  The override prints `fun 1` and returns `true`.

> fun 2: false
>
> 5: b1 equals a1 is false

The variable `b1` is of type `BB`, referring to a `BB` object.  The variable `a1` is of type `AA`, referring to a `AA` object.  The compile-time signature is `equals(AA)`, because that is the most specific match to `equals` that the compiler sees defined on `BB`.  At runtime, that method prints `fun 2` and returns `false`.

> fun 3: true
>
> 6: b2 equals b1 is true

The variables `b1` and `b2` are of type `BB` and they both refer to a `BB` object.  The compile-time signature is `equals(BB)`, because that is the most specific match to `equals` that the compiler sees defined on `BB`.  At runtime, that method prints `fun 3` and returns `false`.

> fun 2: true
>
> 7: b1 equals a4 is true

The variable `b1` is of type `BB` and refers to a `BB` object.  The variable `a4` is of type `AA` and also refers to a `BB` object.  The compile-type signature is `equals(AA)`, because that is the most specific match to `equals` that the compiler sees defined on `BB`.  Despite `a4` really being a `BB`, the static type is `AA`.  At runtime, that method prints `fun 2` and returns `true`.

In summary:

The method chosen is *mostly* decided by the compiler, by the types of the variables involved -- the variable on which the method is called, and the variables passed in as arguments to the method.  The only thing decided at runtime is which *override* (not overload) is chosen based on the runtime type of the object on which the method is called; this is polymorphism.  The runtime types of the argument objects are not considered at runtime.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you very much! Now I truly understand how the code picks the method.